# Summing File Sizes in a Tree Modeling Files and Directories

Tags: java, directory, tree, sum

I have two classes that are supposed to represent files and directories (like the files and directories in a computer). The `File` class holds information about a file such as name and size (which is accessed here with `getSize()`) and the `Directory` class has two lists holding sub-files and sub-directories.

Basically, I'm trying to recursively go through and add up the sizes of all the files in a given `Directory` (and it's sub-directories). Here is my code so far:

```
public int size(Directory localDirect){
    int sum = 0;
    for (File file : this.files){
        sum += file.getSize();
    }
    for (Directory directory : localDirect.directories){
        sum += size(directory);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

When I run this I get a 0 every time irrelevent of the actual file size. My first guess was that since I set `sum` to 0 each method call it is just being reset to 0 each time. However, when I manually follow the logic through I can't figure out why that would reset `sum` since it's set to 0 before the method starts adding the sizes.

Can anyone see what I'm missing or how this could be changed in general to work better?

Answer (score 0):

Oops! Silly mistake, easy fix! It should have been `localDirect.files` in the first enhanced for loop instead of `this.files`. Question resolved.